# How to capture a number while matching a regex?

Tags: python, regex

I am able to edit the file using the following code. I am also able to match the regex and replace it. However, while replacing, I want to capture the number in `(r\d+ ASSRT\)` in the `text1_to_search` and use the same in `replacement1_text`.

Right now, I hardcoded it as `749679`. How can I do that?

```
import fileinput, re

filename = 'epivers.h'
text1_to_search = re.compile(r'#define\s+EPI_VERSION_STR\s+"\d+(?:\.\d+)+\s+\(TOB\)\s+\(r\d+ ASSRT\)"')
replacement1_text = '#define EPI_VERSION_STR         "9.130.27.50.1.2.3 (r749679 ASSRT)"'

for line in fileinput.input(filename, inplace=True, backup='.bak'):
    if text1_to_search.match(line):
        print("match")
    print(text1_to_search.sub(replacement1_text, line))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regular expressions, you can use *capturing groups* to capture individual parts of the search query and make those available in the result. When replacing strings with something else, you can then also use *backreferences* to refer to the value of those groups.

Capturing groups are created by simply wrapping things with parentheses. You have already used non-capturing groups in your expression, which are basically capturing groups prefixed by `?:` which will cause them *not* to be available.

So in your case, you can simply wrap your `r\d+` part with parentheses:

```
re.compile(r'#define\s+EPI_VERSION_STR\s+"\d+(?:\.\d+)+\s+\(TOB\)\s+\((r\d+) ASSRT\)"')
#                                                                     ^^^^^^
```

And then, in your replacement string, you can use `\\1` to refer to that value:

```
replacement1_text = '#define EPI_VERSION_STR         "9.130.27.50.1.2.3 (\\1 ASSRT)"'
```

Simplified example:

```
>>> s = '#define ... "9.130.27.50.1.2.3 (r749679 ASSRT)"'
>>> re.sub('#define .+\((r\d+) ASSRT\)"', '... (\\1 ASSRT)', s)
'... (r749679 ASSRT)'
```